# How to share Xampp database?

Tags: database, xampp

I am using Xampp to host a database that I am currently using for a course project.  However, I need to share this database with my group members so that they can access and have full permissions of the database on their computers.

What I mean by this is not accessing it through SQL, but actually logging into Xampp on their computer and seeing the database there. Any edtis either of us do will update the others.

How can I go about doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you. What do you mean by "Log in to xampp"?

I guess you want access to phpmyadmin from a remote computer?

All you need is to create sql-users with the right permissions. And if you're behind a router you probably want to port forward port 80 and 443..